# VMWare VM as router for windows host

Tags: windows, router, vmware-workstation, pfsense

Goal - use virtual machine as router/firewall for host VM is running on.

I created VMWare VM and installed pfSense. Configured two network adapters for WAN (bridged, VMNet0) and LAN (host-only, VMNet19).

```
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet19:
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.126.2
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.126.128
```

- VM WAN ip: 192.168.0.181
- VM LAN ip: 192.168.126.128

192.168.126.128 being ip of VM leased to it by vmware dhcp service. I entered it manually as gateway because somehow automatically windows does not pick gateway in this case (by the way it does not change a thing it seems).
Finally i opened my lan network adapter properties and unchecked everything except for **VMWare Bridged Protocol** in order to ensure only VM is using it for reaching internet. So far so good - vm can reach internet (pinging external things like google.com works). Problem is host does not get internet access through VMnet19 adapter.

How do i make windows pick up internet connection through this router in virtual machine?

Comment: can you provide the output of "route print" from the command prompt?

Comment: Why do this? It doesn't make sense?